# convert the action name to human readable (e.g. .....1c5..1k)

Tags: transactions, account-name, serialization

I have the follow from using `const tx = api.deserializeTransaction(body.packed_trx);`.

```
{
  "expiration": "1970-07-18T18:12:21.000",
  "ref_block_num": 1544,
  "ref_block_prefix": 84344837,
  "max_net_usage_words": 0,
  "max_cpu_usage_ms": 0,
  "delay_sec": 2,
  "context_free_actions": [],
  "actions": [
    {
      "account": "......k4..4",
      "name": "...k",
      "authorization": [],
      "data": ""
    },
    {
      "account": "",
      "name": ".....1c5..1k",
      "authorization": [],
      "data": ""
    }
  ],
  "transaction_extensions": []
}
```

I would like to derive the human readable action name from `"name": ".....1c5..1k",`.  Ideally with eosjs.

Comment: Should eos-js not do this automatically when deserializing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deserializeTransaction call should return the correct data already. It seems like it's trying to deserialize a transaction from a wrong transaction buffer. The expiration date and other fields don't make sense either. Make sure to parse it as an Uint8Array first. If body.packed_trx is a hex string, you can use this:

```
const txHex = body.packed_trx
const txBytes = new Uint8Array(Buffer.from(txHex, `hex`))
const deserializedTx = api.deserializeTransaction(txBytes);
console.log(`DESERIALIZED TX`, deserializedTx);
```